# Can an event be triggered on a click on a item marker on an html unoredered list?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way to trigger an action when a user clicks on **the icon** of an item in an unordered list? (in javascript and/or jquery)

Comment: Can you provide some code?

Comment: There is. include the content in another tag. Attach a click handler to the `<li>`. In that handler, check if the clicked element was the content wrapepr you added. If so, cancel. Otherwise, go on.

Comment: Is the icon set with CSS?

Comment: Post your code, things you've tried, what you're experiencing vs. what you're trying to achieve, etc.  Please refrain from asking "Write my code for me" questions.  Help us help you by providing as much information as possible!

Comment: If by "icon" you mean the "list item marker" then yes, you can attach a click event to the `<li>` and it will be triggered when you click on the marker. If you need to differentiate between clicking the marker and clicking the list-item, then that becomes problematic.

Comment: @dave not at all. wrap the contents inside another tag, and check the click event's source.

Comment: @JohannesH. Either I am missing something or you are misunderstanding me. I am talking about the list-item-marker that is automatically generated depending on the [list-style-type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/list-style-type), not some separate HTML element. To my knowledge any click event will just reference the source `<li>`. If there is a way to actually differentiate that the marker was clicked as opposed to the content, I'd love to hear about it.

Comment: @dave The click event will always return the innermost element. So if you have something like `<li><span>ELement1</span></li>`, a click on the list-item-marker should return the `<li>`, while a click on the text will return the `<span>`.

Comment: @JohannesH. yeah that makes sense. I think you should post an answer.

Comment: @dave I don't ahve the time to write a proper Javascript fution that does the comparison, but feel free to.

Comment: what do you want to do with the icon on the click event? let me know and I will give you a more complete answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can target just the list item marker if you wish, but it requires wrapping the contents of each item in another tag.

This works because when you assign an event handler to the `<li>` element, that element or any child elements will trigger the handler. Then inside the handler you can check the `nodeName` and it will tell you if the `<li>` was clicked or if it was a child element. Since all contents are wrapped by a `<span>` or a `<div>`, only the list item marker will trigger the event with the target being an `<li>`.

The following runnable example will trigger an alert only when the list item markers are clicked, otherwise the click event is ignored.

```js
$("li").on('click', function(e) {
    if (e.target.nodeName === "LI") {
        alert('You clicked the list item marker');
    } else {
        e.preventDefault(); //a child element was clicked
    }   
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li><span>One</span></li>
    <li><span>Two</span></li>
    <li><span>Three</span></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, is difficult guess you want without your code and mark up but you can try something like this.

HTML

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="" class="icon"></a>
    <a href="" class="icon"></a>
    <a href="" class="icon"></a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

JS

```
$(function() {
  $('a.icon').on('click', function(){
    //your code here...
  });
});
```

- I don't know what html tag your is your 'icon' but this scheme works for whatever you try, just replace the `<a>` for your element and add to it the class `icon`

Answer (score -2):

Yes... use JQUERY.

```
<ul>
    <li>
      <a href="" class="item">Item1</a>
      <a href="" class="item">Item2</a>
    </li>
<ul>
```

Then in your javascript use:

```
$(".item").click(function() {
   var itemIcon = $(this);
   // itemIcon contains the icon that was clicked. Do something with it... 

});
```

Comment: This will trigger on the contents as well as the icon.